# Angular - Conditional click w/ async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, click, pipe, conditional-statements

**I'm attempting to make an element clickable if an async variable is true**

```
    <li (click)='(isThisTrue$ | async) ? openModal() : false'>
```

**I get this error.**

> Template parse errors: Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action
>   expression

**What do you suggest?**

Answer (score 3):

For `button` and `input` elements, the easy solution would be to bind the `disabled` property to the async value. In the present case, you can bind the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property to make the `li` element unresponsive to `click` events:

```
<li (click)="openModal()" [style.pointer-events]="(condition$ | async) ? 'auto' : 'none'">
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-273dth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I really wanted. I'd never used [style.pointer-events]. Thank you for the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

No impact on the DOM :

 *I mean no side effect on the DOM*

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isThisTrue$ | async as isThisTrue">
 <li (click)='isThisTrue ? openModal() : {}'>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: No impact on the DOM? This code hides the `li` element when the condition is `false`.

Comment: Yes of course the impact on the DOM is the visibility of the element, but with ng-container wich is not rendered, you avoid side effects like uh, my <li> is not right under a <ul>

Comment: This didn't work for me because it hides the element if it's false but thank you for your assistance. I needed it to be visible always but the click ability is conditional. Thanks for your knowledge.